# How to use Mint.com outside US/Canada?

Tags: online-tools, websites, mint.com, expense-tracking, tracking

Is it possible to use the [mint.com](https://www.mint.com) service outside US/Canada?

If not (most probably), which similar services also work outside US/Canada?
I'm currently using [TheBirdy](https://thebirdy.com), but it doesn't directly data from credit cards...

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Mint in Canada](https://www.mint.com/canada/). According to [this](https://satisfaction.mint.com/mint/topics/can_mint_be_used_outside_of_the_u_s), Mint is not yet available outside of the U.S. and Canada.

Comment: Sorry for the inaccuracy: I've just edited my question.